# Moments of inner products for Haar random matrices

Tags: probability-theory, mathematical-physics, random-matrices, haar-measure

Let $\mathbf{U}$ be a $n \times n$ Haar orthogonal matrix, $\mathbf{D}$ be a fixed diagonal matrix with half of its entries $+1$ and the remaining half $-1$ and $\left \langle\cdot, \cdot \right \rangle$ denote the Hilbert-Schmidt inner product. I would like to determine whether the following is true.

$$\max_{\left \| M\right \|_{HS}=1} \mathbb{E}\left \langle \mathbf{U}\mathbf{D}\mathbf{U}^*, \mathbf{M}\right \rangle^s =  \mathbb{E}\left \langle \mathbf{U}\mathbf{D}\mathbf{U}^*, \frac{\mathbf{D}}{\sqrt{n}}\right \rangle^s, \: \forall s \geq 1$$

We note that it suffices to consider the statement for $s$ even, since $\left \langle \mathbf{U}\mathbf{D}\mathbf{U}^*, \mathbf{M}\right \rangle \overset{d}{\sim}- \left \langle \mathbf{U}\mathbf{D}\mathbf{U}^*, \mathbf{M}\right \rangle$, for all $\mathbf{M}$. 
In addition, the statement is true for $s = 2$. This follows from expanding the power of the inner product and using results on fourth-order mixed moments of the entries of a Haar orthogonal matrix. 
Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Good question (probably suitable for MO). Did you try using https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/02/08/the-harish-chandra-itzykson-zuber-integral-formula/

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam: Thanks for your comment. I had previously looked into the HCIZ-integral formula. However, here M is not necessarily self-adjoint and, in addition, I am not sure analogous results as in the post you shared are available for Haar orthogonals, rather than unitaries.

Comment: Ha ha, the use of "U" made me think unitary instead of orthogonal. I am not sure but I suspect that Harish-Chandra worked out his formula for a rather general class of Lie groups and not just $U(n)$. The fact that $M$ is not symmetric is more problematic. Nevertheless you can perhaps first study a weaker minimization problem where $M$ is symmetric which immediately reduces to the diagonal case.

Comment: See formulas 4.13 and 4.18 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.11155

Comment: @Abdelmalek Abdesselam: Thanks for the reference. This helps a lot. Also, by a Taylor expansion and dominated convergence, if one shows that the result in question holds, it directly follows that the maximum of the HCIZ integral with D as above over matrices of unit norm also occurs at $D/\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Good, so that means you have a way to test a consequence of your conjecture in the case where the eigenvalues of $D$ are all distinct. The case of $\pm 1$ eigenvalues is more singular but could be treated by a limiting process.

Comment: Having received no answers and having made no progress based on the above comments, I have re-posted on MO at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/395947/moments-of-inner-products-for-haar-random-matrices.